# Onchange on MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, onchange

I have this DDL:

```
<div class="editor-field">           
      @Html.DropDownList("Type", ViewBag.Type as SelectList, "-- Select --")
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Type)
</div>
```

Based on the selected item in this DDL, I want hide an another DDL, in
other words, this 2nd DDL will be displayed only if a specific option
of the first DDL is checked.

The 2nd DDL:

```
<div id="divSimilar" class="editor-field" style="display:none">
     @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SimilarId)            
     @Html.DropDownList("Similar", ViewBag.SimilarId as SelectList, "-- Select --")
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SimilarId)
</div>
```

View:

```
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}

<script type="text/javascript">
var similar = $('#divSimilar');
$('#Type').change(function () {
    var selection = $(this).val();
    if (selection == "Eletronic") {
        similar.show();
    } else {
        similar.hide();
    }
});
</script>
```

When I change the index(value) of my DDL, nothing happens, what can I do?

**EDIT**

Just to show it in browser...

```
<div class="editor-label">
     <label for="Type">Type</label>
</div>
<div class="editor-field">                
    <select data-val="true" data-val-regex="The field Type is not in the correct format." data-val-regex-pattern="^([a-zA-Z\u00c0-\u01ff]([\s]?))+$" data-val-required="The Type field is required." id="Type" name="Type">
       <option value="">-- Select --</option>
       <option value="Eletronic">Eletronic</option>
       <option value="Portable">Portable</option>
    </select>                
    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Type" data-valmsg-replace="true">
    </span>
 </div>

<div id="divSimilar" class="editor-field" style="display:none">
     <label for="SimilarId">Similar</label>
     <select data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Similar must be a number." id="SimilarId" name="SimilarId">
       <option value="">-- Select --</option>
       <option value="1">Headphone</option>
     </select>
     <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="SimilarId" data-valmsg-replace="true">
     </span>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var similar = $('#divSimilar');
    $('#Type').change(function () {
        var selection = $(this).val();
        if (selection == "Eletronic") {
            similar.show();
        } else {
            similar.hide();
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `onchange` attribute and use [unobtrusive javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) (stop polluting your mark-up with behavior)

```
$('#Type').change(function() {
  var selection = $(this).val();
  if (selection == "Eletronic") {
    ...
  } else {
    ...
  }
});
```

however I suggest you wrap both the `<label>` and `<select>` elements inside one element

```
<div id="divSimilar" class="editor-label" style="display:none">
  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SimilarId)
  @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SimilarId, ViewBag.SimilarId as SelectList, "-- Select --")
</div>
```

so you can just use

```
var similar = $('#divSimilar'); // cache it
$('#Type').change(function() {
  var selection = $(this).val();
  if (selection == "Eletronic") {
    similar.show();
  } else {
    similar.hide();
  }
});
```

Side note: Your have other problems as well. You cannot use the same name for both the property your binding to and the `ViewBag`property. Change the `ViewBag` properties to (say) `TypeList` and `SimilarIdList` so that you get correct 2-way model binding.

Note I also assume you have included `jquery-{version}.js` (the view just shows `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")` and not `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")` which needs to come first)

Comment: Hello, thanks for this explanation. I have that reference of jquery in _Layout page, anyway, I added it in my child view. I updated the code in my question, can you take a look? The 2nd DDL isn't doesn't show when I select "Eletronic".

Comment: First you **MUST** roll back your changes. My answer now no longer makes sense. Then I will address the problem

Comment: Next, you did not even follow my advice. You should have 1 `<div>` containing both the `<label>` and the `<select>` and you declare it before the `$('#Type').change() {` line so its cached and the function is not traversing the DOM again each time. The reason is to improve performance, but now you have made it even worse than you original code :)

Comment: Never mind - I have edited it myself (but don't do that again). If its not working then its because you do not have an option with `<option value="Eletronic">....</option>` so you need to check your html. Perhaps you have a typo (the correct spelling is "Electronic") or perhaps your options have values based on an `ID` property (you have not shown how you generate the `SelectList` so I can't be sure) which means you need to check the the `ID` value, or else get the `text()` property of the selected option instead of the `.val()` property.

Comment: Hello, well.. I want to have 2 div's because I use 2 different CSS, anyway, I put all in 1 div only (and make everything as u said). I'm declaring the Select, DDL (whatever) before the script, of course, and of course I have a property "Eletronic", I can send a print screen for you (I depured it..). I just update my code..

Comment: You have one div and use css selectors for styling the elements inside it e.g. `.divSimilar label {...}` to style the label and `.divSimilar select {...}` to style the dropdown.

Comment: Are you still claiming its not working? I have copied the code in your edit into a new project at it works so it its not working you are doing something else wrong. Are you getting any errors in the browser console?

Comment: Thank you, anyway, It was a problem with MVC 4 , I think, I just installed 5 (which comes with the jQuery 1.10), and now it works. Thanks!

Comment: It's not related to MVC (you can use jQuery 1.10 with MVC 4). Possibly there may have been some other conflict with your scripts?

Answer (score -1):

**Instead of your script try this**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 $('#Type').live('change',function() {
    if (value == "Eletronic") {
        $("#divLblSimilar").show();
        $("#divDdlSimilar").show();
    }
    else {
        $("#divLblSimilar").hide();
        $("#divDdlSimilar").hide();
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Please don't use `live` anymore, it is deprecated since jQuery 1.7

Comment: But in my project i am using jquery 1.8. `live` working fine in jquery

Comment: `.live()` was depreciated in v1.7 and removed in v1.9. Don't use it.